SSE with sse-starlette and FastAPI unresponsive
I have just two endpoints in my python code.
One FastAPI endpoint containing logic that takes around minute to be completed.
Another one is SSE endpoint that is using sse-starlette EventSourceResponse.
Both methods are async.
Example
async def report_sse():
    while True:
        global status_changed
        if status_changed:
            status_changed = False
            yield f'status was changed'
        await sleep(1)
        yield " "

@app.get("/sse")
async def sse():
    return EventSourceResponse(report_sse())

and
@app.post("/heavy")
async def heavy_endpoint():
# some long running code here

The problem is that when heavy endpoint is running, then sse is not called anymore.
Could please someone provide similar example or tell me how I can solve it?
I have tried to use queue and threads for heavy endpoint

I was able to solve it with  await asyncio.to_thread added to long running operation
